# Meaning of に in 早くに

Tags: particle-に, adverbs

These constructions both have Google hits: [もっと早く**に**言う](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%82%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8%E6%97%A9%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AB%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86%22) and [もっと早く言う](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%82%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8%E6%97%A9%E3%81%8F%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86%22).

They seem to mean more or less the same thing. But what exactly does this に mean and when can we use に after an adverb?

I don't think we can say stuff like *`強くに叩く` for just any adverb.

Maybe it adds some temporal nuance, like までに expressing a deadline? Is this phenomenon limited to 早くに?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

早く in 早く言う is (functioning as) an adverb (or, the adverbial form of the i-adjective 早い.)
早く in 早くに言う is a noun (the noun form of the i-adjective 早い -- 形容詞「早い」の連用形「早く」が名詞になったもの). So 「早く+に」 is literally "at + an early time".

Similar examples of this noun form:

> - 遅く -- こんな**遅く**に何の用だ
> - 遠く -- **遠く**で雷が鳴っている
> - 近く -- **近く**まで来た
> - 深く -- 海の**深く**に沈む

Not all i-adjectives work like this　(eg 美しく, 明るく, 大きく can not be a noun.) Only several i-adjectives expressing the degree of time and space have this noun form (eg 遅く, 早く, 近く, 遠く, 深く, 古く, 高く, 低く).